# Is string concatenation vulnerable to null character in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, path-injection, null-byte-injection

I just see this line of code in VB in one file .aspx

```
FileUpload.SaveAs(sPath & "/" & FileUpload.FileName)
```

This line save a file that an user uploaded. It use the [SaveAs method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I was worried about the **sPath** because the user can edit it.

The user can only save image, so it check the filename extension. I thought someone can use a null character to save another file, like:

```
/path/evil.aspx0x00/image.jpg
```

Fortunately, this don't work. But is there another way to manipulate? Can someone send another way of null character?

-- Edit

As far I know, I list this types of null character

- `0x00`
- `%00`
- `/0`
- `/x0`
- `&#0;`
- `&#x0;`

There is more?

--Edit 2

Lol, [this list give more types of null character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

FileUpload.FileName is fully user-specified.  It can contain "/../" and other similar path escape sequences, so you can't trust it.

If you're saving the file to disk, the best thing to do would be to ignore the user-provided filename and to create your own guaranteed safe filename instead.  For instance, you could generate a new GUID to accomplish this.  If you absolutely must use the user-provided filename, consider restricting it to only { alphanumeric characters, hyphen, underscore, period } and enforce that the filename must begin and end with an alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 1):

In a file upload mechanism a few things should always be considered to be checked, basic checking on file extensions only is not sufficient enough in my opinion.

1. **File header checking:** Read the first few bytes of the file and determine if it is an image or not.
2. **Convert the image:** If step 1 is successful, convert the image to a format other than the uploaded format. This is to delete possible malicious code in images.

As far as your question regarding nullbyte injection: Besides 0x00, %00 can also be used in file names, for example:

```
/path/evil.aspx%00.jpg
```

I doubt this will work in ASPX but depends on your configuration.

Comment: lol, I already tested of %00. I understand that it need to check the file type. But the guys are saying it is too dificult for every type. They say they can't see a way to break it.

Comment: As far I know, I tested for 0x00, %00, %00000. I see if I send " or & the function say it is a ilegal character for file name.